# Is it fraud per se to falsely claim your non-profit has distributed donations in soliciting further donations?

Tags: fraud, non-profit

Say you run a non-profit organization dedicated to supporting a cause. You solicit and receive donations for that cause. In soliciting further donations you talk about all the past donations you've distributed to the cause your organization supports. But in fact this is not true; you have not distributed a single cent. You have not stolen the money, and in fact once the story hits the press you do distribute it all as promised. But does the fact that you made false claims about your organization's actions in the process of soliciting donations (which you might not have received without your false claims) constitute legal fraud per se?

This is somewhat of a general curiosity, as I suspect this would vary based on specific jurisdiction (I believe the case occurred in the US, but don't know exactly where).

Comment: "Fraud *per se*" is not a thing.

Comment: ...yes. The question is whether the described act per se is fraud, or whether fraud requires additional acts (e.g. you steal the money donated).

Comment: By the way, if anyone is curious what this is all about, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giaoY2DlVr8&t=1s&pp=ygUVY29tcGxldGlvbmlzdCBjaGFyaXR5 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMzjxizna_g&pp=ygUVY29tcGxldGlvbmlzdCBjaGFyaXR5